# Именование элементов в схеме разделения данных, GUI etc

Tags: c#, ооп, asp.net, архитектура, именование

Не могу придумать, как бы правильнее назвать абстракции в сотворенной мной *"надстройке"* для `ASP.NET-MVC`. Постараюсь рассказать подробнее:

Представим такой типичный контроллер:

```
public class CabinetController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Settings() { ... }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Settings(Foo foo) { ... }
}
```

Глядя на сей код, легко предположить, что это некий контроллер, управляющий личным кабинетом пользователя и позволяющий обновить некоторые настройки

Правда, я здесь вижу несколько проблем:

- Указанные 2 действия связаны своей логикой, что плохо прослеживается
  при таком подходе к написанию контроллера (к примеру, между ними
  может встать куча других методов и визуально *"разорвать"* их тонкую
  *связь*)
- Каждое действие обладает спектром собственных логических свойств:

  1. Проверка, имеет ли пользователь доступ к данной странице
  2. Инициализация модели, передаваемой в представление
  3. Опционально - повторная проверка доступа (к примеру, какие-то данные
     мы достали из БД, чего бы не стали делать, если у пользователя итак
     нет возможности попасть на страницу в виду каких-то менее затратных
     проверок)
  4. Последующая наконец загрузка представления
  5. Если добавить еще и щепотку мультиязычности, то каждое действие также
     приобретает свойство текущей культуры пользователя и механизм
     локализации данных
- Любой метод контроллера может быть интерпретирован как валидный метод для обработки данных пользователя, если вдруг Вы случайно забыли указать атрибут `[NonAction]` (прекрасно ясно, что это может привести к разным нехорошим последствиям)

И тут я подумал: а почему бы `Settings` быть не двумя разными методами, а одним классом с единой логикой и разными вариантами инициализации?

Вот так и появилась моя "надстроечка" хД

---

Типичная и хорошо Вам знакомая MVC-структура:

- ProjectName

  - Models

    - [Some model].cs
  - Views

    - [ControllerName]

      - [ViewName].cshtml
  - Controllers

    - [ControllerName]Controller.cs

---

Структура моей *"надстройки"*:

- ProjectName

  - Models // (?)

    - [ControllerName]

      - [ViewName].cs
  - Views

    - [ControllerName]

      - [ViewName].cshtml

---

Как по мне, такая структура выглядит куда более интуитивно

Приведу пример `[ViewName].cs` на примере затронутого ранее метода `Settings`:

```
// Класс обертка по большей части нужен только для того, чтобы знать,
// к какому контроллеру относить описанные в нем действия (также его можно заменить атрибутом)

// Очень сомневаюсь, что сюда подходит название "Model",
// однако это и не контроллер в типичном его понимании
public partial class CabinetModel : Model
{
    // Так как класс отвечает за загрузку определенной страницы, 
    // "обозвал" его PageLoader. Однако это имя ему как-то не идет
    public class Settings : PageLoader
    {
        // Метод будет вызван в случае HttpGet запроса, так как не указаны аттрибуты,
        // а также метод не имеет параметров
        public void Initialize() { ... }

        // Метод будет вызван в случае HttpPost запроса, так как не указаны аттрибуты,
        // а также метод имеет входные параметры
        public void Initialize(Foo foo) { ... }
    }
}
```

---

Так вот, мой вопрос заключается в следующем: имеет ли право на жизнь такая концепция, а также как мне следует переименовать классы `Model` и `PageLoader`, чтобы они смотрелись более органично?

Comment: _между ними может встать куча других методов и визуально "разорвать" их тонкую связь_ - структуру классов нужно смотреть не в редакторе кода, а в окне Class View или Object Browser (в Visual Studio; в других IDE могут быть свои средства).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: таки это само собой, сей пункт больше идет просто как дополнение. Главным я считаю то, что представленные методы скорее носят в себе задатки объектов с определенным встроенным функционалом)

Answer (score 2):

Всякая концепция имеет право на жизнь, просто у каждого своя логика. (И я к вашей концепции отношусь весьма критически)

Я вот не понимаю: если у вас есть некий пользователь — то зачем вам нужна ещё одна модель, проставьте настройки пользователю.

Если из двадцати настроек пользователя вы вдруг хотите настроить пять, относящихся к некоей абстракции "личный кабинет" — ну и настройте, зачем для этого создавать новую абстракцию "настройки личного кабинета" в виде модели? Создайте модель представления.

В качестве источника для вдохновения посмотрите asp.net identity — в нём, когда происходит редактирование одного поля, например пароль — не создаётся новая модель/сущность, происходит работа с моделью пользователь, но работа идёт с некоторой моделью представления (старый пароль, новый пароль, подтверждение пароля).

Вот например, модель пользователя:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    ...

    [Required]
    public DateTime Registered { get; set; }

    public int? CityId { get; set; }

    public City City { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

А вот например ResetPasswordViewModel

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

Мне кажется, что то, что вы называете "надстройка" — это лишнее, используйте обычные модели представления.

Вот например штатные модели представления в asp.net identity:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вполне вероятно, что когда у вас станет нет пять настроек личного кабинета, а двадцать пять - вы захотите разделить логику, например отдельно билинговую информацию показать (пять полей), отдельно адрес (другие пять полей). Согласитесь, вполне удобно когда вьюмодель называется "ВойтиПоДвухФакторнойАвторизации" или "СменитьГород" — сразу понятно какой сценарий обрабатывается.

Вообще, очень легко создавать всё новые и новые абстракции ("все проблемы можно решить созданием дополнительной обёртки, кроме проблемы излишнего числа обёрток"), но зачем? Поэтому я бы рекомендовал так не делать, как вы хотите.

У вас при таком подходе нарушается Single Responsibility Principle с движением в сторону god object. Было два метода — стал один мегаметод. Вы говорите "единый", но это не всегда хорошо.

Но — если уж вам так хочется сходить в эту сторону — то отговаривать не буду: каждый опыт является важным и полезным, если он делается осознанно.

Отдельно, сверх того, что вас интересует в данном вопросе хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что ваши контроллеры просто пухнут от логики, лучше подумайте, как сделать их "тоньше". Ваши два метода и так были достаточно крупными, а вы их ещё и объединить хотите.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь объемлющий ответ! Хочу все же подметить, что я не собирался отказываться от классических моделей (если не следовать принципу единственной ответственности, то, как Вы правильно подметили, класс может катастрофически распухнуть). То, что предлагаю я, скорее является заменой привычным контроллерам, но не гибридом с самой моделью (название `Model` сильно сбивает с толку). Да, стал один мега-метод, но он как раз-таки позволяет очень легко настроить правила доступа к самому себе, поведение в случае его отсутствия, правило определения культуры пользователя и ее применения

Comment: По сути, приведенный мною код аналогичен тому, что бы Вы записали в методах самого контроллера (лично я, к примеру, всю бизнес-логику увожу в модели, чтобы контроллеры как раз и не пухли), просто в моем случае под катом уже определены все необходимые вещи (алгоритм обработки запроса пользователя из вопроса), которые можно легко и гибко перенастроить для любого такого "контроллера"

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Не вижу, где же вы всю логику увели в модели, чтобы контроллеры не пухли: у вас пять пунктов написано, что вы делаете в экшене контроллера. Пять, Карл! А в бизнес-логике тогда что, тридцать пять их раз "ну пять -- это так мало"? Вы когда рисовали структуру папок -- чётко видно, что у вас по сравнению с штатной структурой mvc стало на целый уровень больше. А вы щупали Razor Pages в core, где наоборот, убрали целый уровень? Нужно понимать, что слои абстракции -- это не бесплатно, а напротив очень дорого!

Comment: нет, ну погодите. Положим, у пользователя нет доступа к странице. И как это должно отразиться на ViewModel? Обычно в таких случаях пользователя просто отправляют лесо... на другую страницу, а ViewModel даже не проходит инициализацию. Проверка доступа может (и по-хорошему должна) находиться во ViewModel, но вот ветвлением исходов уже управляет контроллер (на то он и контроллер)... Может, конечно, я жил во лжи все эти годы, тогда поправьте меня, пожалуйста хД

Comment: таки да, мы как бы ушли на ещё один уровень вниз. Ключевое тут «как бы» хД Можете сказать, что я занимаюсь хренью, но я балуюсь с генерацией сборок, так что все написанное будет преобразовано в обычные контроллеры. А вот это я делаю для удобства разработки. По крайней мере стараюсь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov  А сделайте вот что. Когда вы допилите свою генерацию сборок -- приходите через полгода-год в этот вопрос и напишите, что вы в итоге реализовали (ответите на свой вопрос по неймингу) и опишите не только схему, как и что было сделано -- но и как развивалось со временем эта система. Это будет очень хорошим дополнением в вашу же тему, как вам такое предложение?

Comment: А знаете, таки хорошая идея) Попутно за это время заимею мнение общественности на тему того, насколько полезна/бесполезная сия вещица)